# Oracle Apex Websheet - '???' Javascript Error on APPLY_CHANGES

Tags: oracle

At my organization we are using Apex Websheets for maintaining our wiki. During editing of page contents, when 'Apply Changes' button is clicked the browser often gives javascript alert showing the following message:

**Alert box title**: Message from webpage
   **Alert box message**: ???

Once this error occurs all the changes needs to be discarded (as there is no other option available to save the changes). Has anybody faced the similar problem or this is unique to our environment?

Server/Client Configuration:
   - Oracle Linux 32-bit 
   - Oracle 11g Release1 (11.1.0.7)
   - Application Express 4 (4.1.1.00.23)
   - Tested in Internet Explorer 8 (8.0.7600.16385) and Firefox 17 (17.0.1) on Windows 7 32-bit